# JIRA maven - upgrading to httpclient 4.x

Tags: maven, jira, apache-httpclient-4.x, jira-plugin

I'm building a JIRA plugin. At this point, I need to create a service to upload attachments, hence the need to use HttpPost and MultipartEntityBuilder, etc..

To use HttpPost, I need to add org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient as a dependency in my pom.xml

So, in my pom.xml, I have added the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>logkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also added !com.sun.jdmk.comm and !java.jmx to my Import-Package:

```
<Import-Package>
    org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
    org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
    !com.sun.jdmk.comm, !javax.jms, *
</Import-Package>
```

Even with all the changes and the dependencies I've added, I still can't get my plugin to run. I keep getting this error:

> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]         'com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin' -
>   'myPlugin'  failed to load. [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]             Cannot
>   start plugin: com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin [INFO]
>   [talledLocalContainer]                Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   com.atlassian.tutorial.myPlugin [162]: Unable to resolve 162.0:
>   missing requirement [162.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)

Before getting this error, I got an error about "com.sun.jdmk.comm", which is why I added it to my Import-Package, now I'm doing the same for "java.jms" but I can't solve the problem.

I'm just trying to use httpclient 4.2.5, why is it so troublesome :(

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to use httpclient 4.2.5?

Please advise.

Thanks!